# ValueError trying to format a date with datetime.strptime in python

Tags: python, datetime

If I do this:

```
dss = datetime.date.today()
print dss.strftime('%d/%m/%y %I:%M %p')
```

I get: `12/03/13 12:00 AM`

But, if I do:

```
print datetime.datetime.strptime("10/25/09 03:01 AM",'%d/%m/%y %I:%M %p')
```

I get

```
ValueError: time data '10/25/09 03:01 AM' does not match format  '%d/%m/%y %I:%M %p'
```

What am I overlooking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are giving a date in m/d/y format when the required format is d/m/y.  It is having trouble converting 25 to a month

Comment: Ouch! Thanks a lot. I guess I needed that second pair of eyes.

Comment: Third pair.  I missed it too :).  It's too bad that `datetime` doesn't give a more instructive error here ...